# Как выполнить однотипное действие с разными полями модели в Django/Python

Tags: python, django, функции

Например, есть модель

```
class Model(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.CharField()
    field3 = models.CharField()
    ...
```

В Views я пишу метод, в котором хочу по очереди обратиться к полям экземпляра модели и изменить их значение, например с помощью такой конструкции

```
model.field1.some_functions(args1)
model.field2.some_functions(args2)
model.field3.some_functions(args3)
...
```

Могу ли я организовать некий перебор по полям модели, указав выполнить одинаковое действие, вместо того, чтобы явно прописывать для каждого поля метод работы с ним?

Вопрос не столько про django, сколько про python в целом.

Comment: Это [описано в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model).

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Мне нужно не извлечь поля, а обратиться к ним.

Comment: Что вам мешает использовать цикл по кортежу полей или map для него?

Comment: Только незнание о такой возможности, спасибо!

Comment: Добрый совет: Стоит сначала хорошо изучить Python, а уж потом браться за Django. А то ждёт вас масса неприятных сюрпризов.

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Я джун, мне многое непонятно. На работе приходится в очень быстрых темпах что-то изучать, в этот раз django, многое на самостоятельном изучении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `getattr`.

Код:

```
select_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', ... ] # нужные поля
for field_str in select_fields:
    # field_str - это строка (название поля)
    field = getattr(model, field_str) # model - это ваш класс
    field.somefunction()
```

У `getattr` мы первым аргументом передаём класс, а вторым название элемента в виде строки.
*Надеюсь помог*

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ, применил у себя. Не знал о такой возможности, очень здорово